# QTP 11 is not able to identify Firefox 17.0.1

Tags: qtp

QTP 11  is not able to identify Firefox 17.0.1.Which patch we need to install and where can we get it?

Answer (score 1):

Support for Firefox 17 was added with patch QTPWEB_00122 you can get it on [HP's support site](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/patches) (HP Passport required).

Other Firefox patches for QTP 11 are:

- FF19: QTPWEB_00127
- FF20-22: QTPWEB_00129